# What is the meaning of module.exports? Why is it called module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Also, the second question. I'm beginner at express. Do you know of any good websites where I can learn? The documentations are most of the time vague and therefore not so easy for a beginner. Thanks

Comment: Try to learn from Tutorials of CodewithMosh https://codewithmosh.com. It has Node.js course, where you call learn both nodejs and express.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module encapsulates related code into a single unit of code. When creating a module, this can be interpreted as moving all related functions into a single file. When you want to use this encapsulated functions in another file, you should import them into your current working file. exports object decides what functions can be imported and what are private for the file only. Below `sayHelloInEnglish` can be imported, but `sayGoodbye` can not.

```
exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function() {
    return "HELLO";
};

sayGoodbye = function(){
    return "Goodbye";
}
```